# GraphicsGrid with empty elements

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-layouts

Here is a nice figure

[image]

Now let's create a grid

```
plot = Show[GraphicsGrid[{{im1, im1, im1}, 
            {SpanFromLeft, im1, im1}, 
            {SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, im1}}, Spacings -> 0]]
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see, three dots (...) appear at the empty slots of the grids.

My question: Is there a way to remove these dots?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
im1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Kuf.jpg"];
UpperTriangularize@Array[1 &, {3, 3}] /. {1 -> im1, 0 -> ""} // GraphicsGrid
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Thanks to Kuba && J. M.. I didn't know I could use "" instead of a white rectangle. And J. M.'s method is more compact.

Comment: `blank = ""` will be enough.

Comment: As Kuba says, `""` suffices. Here's a compact version: `GraphicsGrid[PadLeft[{{im1, im1, im1}, {im1, im1}, {im1}}, Automatic, ""]]`

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `Null` instead of `SpanFromLeft`:

```
im1=Graphics[Disk[]];

plot = Show[GraphicsGrid[{{im1, im1, im1}, 
        {Null, im1, im1}, 
        {Null, Null, im1}}, Spacings -> 0]]
```

This will produce no dots.